# Render a template on it's own ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

How can I render a template without it being inside it's parent.

For example, I need to render the login template, but I do not want it to be inside the index template.

So I want the login template to be on it's own. Is this possible?

Comment: Use the renderTemplate hook in the route. http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/

Comment: @blessenm that will still render the template inside an outlet. I want to render a template just on it's own. Not in an outlet.

Answer (score 0):

```
App.FooView = Em.View.extend({

});


var foo = App.FooView.create();
foo.appendTo('#somewhere');
```

and to remove

```
foo.remove();
```

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html

http://emberjs.com/guides/views/defining-a-view/

Comment: I don't fully understand. I have a template named `login_template` so I went ahead and set `templateName` to `login_template` but how do I make it so only the `login_template` shows and the when you go out of that route everything is back to normal? 

In index template I have some general things and then an outlet. So I want that to be the normal thing, aside from when you're in the login route. In which case it should only show the login template.

Comment: It sounds like you should just create a login route, and redirect to the login route.

Comment: I added a small example for a different question, that's similar.

Comment: I have a login route and everything. It's just that my login template always renders in the `outlet` like it's suppose to but I want it to replace the index template as a whole, and just render it self and not anything else. As for the rest of my routes, they should render as normal, in the index template's outlet.